# About templates in C++

Tags: c++, templates

Why isn't this working?
I am new to c++.
And why is & used in function parameters?
How can I use templates?

```
template <typename T>
void swap(T&a,T&b)
{
    T temp=a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
}
```

Comment: How isn't it working?

Comment: if you have `using namespace std;` you might have problem, else it should work (version with `std::move` would be better though.)

Comment: `std::swap` already exists https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap take care what you are testing.  Please read [ask] with a [mcve] and include any error messages  and explain what you mean by _"Why isn't this working?..."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's already a standard [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) function with the same signature. If you're `using namespace std` in the same scope, it's likely there's a conflict.